# How to set default branch for GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

With `GitPython`, I can create a new repo with the following:

```py
from git.repo.base import Repo

Repo.init('/tmp/some-repo/')
```

The repo is created with the default branch `master`.

How can I modify this default branch?

**Update**: As suggested in the answers below, I have tried using `Repo.init('/tmp/some-repo', initial_branch="main"`), however it renders this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/checker/tests.py", line 280, in test_alternative_compare_branch
    comp_repo_main = Repo.init(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 937, in init
    git.init(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 542, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 1005, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/git/cmd.py", line 822, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(129)
  cmdline: git init --initial-branch=main
  stderr: 'error: unknown option `initial-branch=main'
```

In the git docs, it states that the command for setting initial branch is `--initial-branch` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init/2.28.0#Documentation/git-init.txt---initial-branchltbranch-namegt).

Judging by the error, I think that the additional kwargs feature of GitPython is not including the `--` prefix.

Comment: what is in `repo`? did you clone it, or is it an existing local directory? What's the purpose of this - do you want to skip cloning some objects or just want to find a way to checkout an existing branch using gitpython?

Comment: Hi @Marat, the `repo` is a new repo I have initialised using. I made a typo in the code above... I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.init), `init` takes the same arguments as `git init` as keyword arguments. You do have to turn `-` into `_`.

```
from git import Repo

Repo.init('/tmp/some-repo/', initial_branch='main')
```

---

***UPDATE***

[`initial-branch` was added very recently](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32ba12dab2acf1ad11836a627956d1473f6b851a) in v2.28.0. You'll need to upgrade Git to use it.

If you can't, manually change the branch name with `branch.rename(new_name)`. Unfortunately you can't do this until *after* the first commit, no branches truly exist yet. That's a Git limitation and why they added `initial-branch` and also the [`init.defaultBranch` config option](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8747ebb7cde9e90d20794c06e6806f75cd540142).

Comment: Yes I did see that but when I try your example it throws an error: `stderr: 'error: unknown option initial-branch=main'`... I need the two `--` prefix but I can't figure out how to set it.

Comment: @LondonAppDev It's `initial_branch`. Note the underscore. You do not need the `--`.

Comment: Hey @Schwern, yes I tried that, but it didn't work. I edited the post with the details. Thanks for responding though!

Comment: @LondonAppDev That shows it's running `git init --initial-branch=main` which is correct. Check what version of Git GitPython is using. `from git import Git`, `g = Git()` and `g.version_info`.